# Data not shown in the tabulator table

Tags: database, show, tabulator

I will close my first question and will asked here again, a little bit more structured.
I have a database (mysql/mariadb) from which I will show the datas in the tabulator-table.
When I store the incoming data at first in a json-file, it looks good. When I used the json_encode($output) directly I get an error.
First case:
My index.php:

```
<?php
        require 'php/dbCon.php';
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery- 
ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabulator.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

    <script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"> 
</script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tabulator.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery_wrapper.js"></script>

    <script src="js/tt_kcal.js"></script>
    
    <head>
    <h2>Testseite</h2>
    </head>

    <body>

    Tabellendaten:
        <div id="example-table"></div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

My query php - case 1 -

```
<?php
    include 'php/dbCon.php';
    ?>

    <?php
    $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM `kcaltab` WHERE `id`<=25";
    $result = $conn->query($myQuery);
    $output = array();
    $output = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $sresult = json_encode($output);
    $fp = fopen('json_kcaltab.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    ?>
```

my js-file - case 1 -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        data:"json_kcaltab.json",
        layout:"fitColumns",
        placeholder:"warte auf Daten",
        columns: [
                    {title:"ID", field:"ID"},
                    {title:"Lebensmittel", field:"Lebensmittel", hozAlign:"left"},
                    {title:"Bemerkungen", field:"Bemerkungen"},
                    {title:"Einheit", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"Kcal", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"KH", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"Eiweiss", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"Fett", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"ELgr", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"TLgr", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"eindat", field:"eindat", hozAlign:"center"},
                ],
        });
    });
```

the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwIRO.png)

By the second case, only the query-php-file and the js-file will changed a little bit:

case 2 - query:

```
    <?php
        include 'php/dbCon.php';
    ?>

    <?php
    $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM `kcaltab` WHERE `id`<=25";
    $result = $conn->query($myQuery);
    $output = array();
    $output = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    ?>
```

js-file - case 2 -
$(document).ready(function() {

```
    var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        data:"mySql_kcalgesamt.php",
        layout:"fitColumns",
        placeholder:"warte auf Daten",
        columns: [
                    {title:"ID", field:"ID"},
                    {title:"Lebensmittel", field:"Lebensmittel", hozAlign:"left"},
                    {title:"Bemerkungen", field:"Bemerkungen"},
                    {title:"Einheit", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"Kcal", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"KH", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"Eiweiss", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"Fett", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"ELgr", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"TLgr", field:"Einheit", hozAlign:"center"},
                    {title:"eindat", field:"eindat", hozAlign:"center"},
                ],
        });
    });
```

and the result comes with an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3YI4.png)

I would be very excited if someone can help me (and trying to explain the mistake I make to myself). Thanks a lot.

Dieter Ascheberg

Hi, now I have changed my js-file as Double H. said as follows:

```
    ".....
    ajaxURL: "mySql_kcalgesamt.php",
    ajaxConfig:"GET",
    ajaxContentType:"json",
    ......"
```

and now I get the following error message in the web.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf0vJ.png)
but in the "Rapid PHP Editor 2020" everything works fine.
You can see the site at wss-sh.de.
Had someone a solution for me?

- 2022.02.12
  Now, everything works fine in my development area, only when I bring that to my server I get the json-error. Now I think it could be, that my json-file had a empty line or a space at the beginning (see the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWKra.png), which is the reason for the error message.
  Can anyone help me, to clean up this error?
  Thanks in advance.
  Dieter

Comment: change your `data` key with `ajaxURL`  in js file

Comment: Can you explain it a litten bit more? I try it with ajax, but it didn't work because I have no experience with that. Thank you vry mich.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, all what I must do is to delete the

```
"<?php" and the "?>"
```

at the beginning of the query-php-file. Then the json had no space or empty line. Thanks TK1234 at the php.de/forum for the solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).